# flutter run, dependencies in IOS

Tags: flutter

I try to create an flutter app. i start create Android project in ubuntu it works very fine. But then i mvoe the project into MacOS (Update system 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.4.1) then i get error compile into a real IOS device.

Here is my output:

```
frederikfrnadsen@demos-MBP barcode $ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Found saved certificate choice "iPhone Developer: Frederik Frandsen (W5W828HUYY)". To clear, use "flutter config".
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "iPhone Developer: Frederik Frandsen (W5W828HUYY)"
Running pod install...                                              1,7s
Running Xcode build...                                                  

Xcode build done.                                           17,6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/frederikfrnadsen/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_barcode_scanner-0.1.7/ios/Classes/FlutterBarcodeScannerPlugin.m:2:9: fatal error:
    'flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner-Swift.h' file not found
    #import <flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner-Swift.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Try: (rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework)

it works for me !